# Does it matter if a brute force search for a password returns a collision and not the password?

Tags: hash, brute-force, password-cracking

Assume the following very basic hashing algorithm.

`h(k) = k mod 17`

Let's say we create a password `12345` for a website that uses this very basic hashing algorithm.  That would yield the hash of 3.

Say a brute force attacker comes by and starts guessing numbers starting at 1 they would only have to get to 3 before they got a hash collision and obviously 3 is not the original password.

Is the problem that the password hashing space (0-16) is much smaller than the space of the allowed password, or is there something else I'm overlooking?

Comment: I've updated your title in an attempt to better reflect your question at the end.  If you don't like my change you can revert it or just edit it again.

Comment: As a note: Yes, the reason for collisions is that the hashing space is smaller than the input space. This is true for all hash algorithms, and is called the [Pigeonhole_principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[Steffen's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/227213/149676) covers this perfectly, but I just wanted to add a few more details.

#### Anything that gives a match is usually fine

As he says, you generally don't care about finding the actual password, because many applications will be happy to authenticate you with any string that happens to hash to the hash value stored in the database.  This is most often true for web applications, [but may be less often the case in other contexts](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227211/does-it-matter-if-a-brute-force-search-for-a-password-returns-a-collision-and-no/227214#comment464811_227214).  This means that if you perform a brute force search and find something with the same hash, you can login to the account even if it isn't actually the same password.  This, as implied in the question, is the nature of hashing and is a direct result of the [pigeonhole principle](https://steemit.com/technology/@jiansoo/the-pigeonhole-principle-how-do-pigeons-and-pigeonholes-relate-to-cryptographic-hashing-functions-and-the-number-of-hairs-on).

#### Until you need the actual password

However, there may be some cases where you **do** want to find the original password.  This would be the case if for instance a hacker stole a username/password from a valueless service and wanted to try to login as the user on a more valuable service (Facebook, banks, etc...).  Since people often use the same password everywhere, then in this case you really do want the original password - not just something that hashes to the same value for a given hashing algorithm (after all, different services may use different hashing methods, and most also use [cryptographic salts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) - [h/t @Taemyr](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227211/does-it-matter-if-a-brute-force-search-for-a-password-returns-a-collision-and-no/227214#comment464806_227214)).

#### But the difference doesn't matter

Fortunately (for our attacker), this doesn't really matter.  The reason is because an exhaustive brute force is effectively impossible.  Instead a hacker will try things that are likely to be passwords (word lists, common passwords, etc...).  As a counter example imagine that despite the impossibility of it you have a hash from a web service and manage to perform a brute force search on all possible 256 bit ASCII strings.  You find three inputs that hash to the same value as the user's password hash:

1. `BD3EDF42F6D3AF2DAAE93313EB534`
2. `7AF7B8B8F84443872C48EC372DBD1`
3. `password`

Which would you guess is the actual password?  The answer is clearly #3.  I mean, there is technically a chance that the user just happened to pick an extremely strong password (i.e. `BD3EDF42F6D3AF2DAAE93313EB534`) that just happened to hash to the same value as `password`, but the odds of that are effectively zero.

In this sense the attacker has a nice advantage.  They would prefer to find the actual password, and it turns out that because people are bad at picking random passwords, the best way to do that isn't by checking everything anyway - it's by checking things that look like passwords.  This makes brute forcing searching much, much, much, much more effective, and also gives the attacker a much more useful result (the actual password, rather than some random string that happens to have the same hash).

Comment: Even the other side using the same algorithm is insufficient.  They have to use the same algorithm and have the same salt.

Comment: @Taemyr: Exactly. As a matter of fact, that is the whole point of using a salt - to make sure that identical passwords do not result in the same hash, because that would be bad, as shown here. I edited to mention that.

Comment: In some circumstances, having the hash only seems to help you. For example, zip encryption and MS Office documents encryption encrypt the password to a hash, check the hash when you're trying to decrypt, and if the hash matches, use the original password to do the actual decryption. There's zero chance of `password` decrypting your file correctly if your password was `BD3EDF42F6D3AF2DAAE93313EB534`, even if both have the same hash.

Comment: I disagree with the “an exhaustive brute force is effectively impossible”, while for the lay person maybe; but for something with the resources and time, it’s not. That’s what helps give supercomputer and botnet farms viability. In many ways it’s similar to how crytomining works.

Comment: For my chosen example (a 256 bit string) it is in fact impossible to perform an exhaustive brute force search: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack#Theoretical_limits

Comment: @vol7ron whoops, forgot to tag you in my response.  Also see here: https://www.reddit.com/r/theydidthemath/comments/1x50xl/time_and_energy_required_to_bruteforce_a_aes256/

Comment: @ConorMancone thanks for the follow up I’ll take a look.

Comment: I can give a counter-example. Suppose the password-hash algorithm had the property that if you could try all eight-character passwords, you would expect to find 1-2 hits, but the site minimum is ten characters. The short matches are all wrong.

Comment: @vol7ron Even if you used all computing power on Earth for thousands of years you still wouldn't be able to bruteforce something like AES encryption. Note however that tomorrow someone could find an attack that reduces the complexity from say 2^256 to 2^64 and *that* would change a lot. Currently we cannot exclude that something like that exists. We know that quantum computing can reduce the complexity by the square root (which would make AES-128 insecure since it would require "only" 2^64 computations, but AES-256 would still be safe enough).

Comment: @Bakuriu You’ve made the assumption that AES is used, which I’ve never seen stated anywhere above. Even considering AES-128, which is still very secure, it is said it’d take a billion billion (quintillion) years. There’s no objection to theoretical limits. What isn’t explores are realistic limits. The source of information and time period can be very indicative of the bytes that were sequenced. If you can restrict your options to those bytes, it reduces the complexity when brute forcing, which is why numbers and special characters are now required. How much time might that shave?

Comment: @vol7ron The answer explicitly talks about _exhaustive_ brute force. Restricting to likely combinations is precisely what the answer is saying _does_ happen, but by definition it's not _exhaustive_. The whole point is that arbitrary sequences of bytes which happen to collide with the real password will probably never be found, because the attacker would only try those byte sequences if they were trying _all_ byte sequences, not targeting those which are most likely.

Comment: @IMSoP I don’t have an issue with the answer as much, but I do have to bring into focus the OP, which does not express an opinion about degree of difficult or method of algorithm/scheme. “Exhaustive” is a relative term and in this case and really depends on methodology.  I think we’re in agreement whether it be AES or twofish, or even an RSA or SHA monodirectional hashing; brute-force is challenging and improbable with today’s technology; though, we should also consider that there is technology that exists that is not publicly available, the bounds and limitations of which are uncertain.

Answer (score 18):

The main goal of brute forcing is not to get the original password but to get a password that works. Thus it does not matter much if the found password was not the original one as long as it works.

It is very likely though that with efficient and intelligent brute forcing based on a dictionary of common passwords and typical modifications the resulting password will actually be the real one. This is simply because most users don't use long random passwords but common passwords with typical modifications and thus the real passwords will be found first when doing intelligent brute forcing.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it matter if a brute force search for a password returns a collision and not the password?

There are other answers addressing this question quite well, so I'll explore a different angle: It doesn't matter, because brute-force searches are unlikely to ever find a collision instead of the original password.

Assumptions:

- The password is shorter than the maximum length by some number of characters.
- The brute-force search tries every character, starting with the shortest possible password.
- The implementation has a very low probability of collisions. This is [true even for deprecated algorithms like MD5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201705/how-many-random-elements-before-md5-produces-collisions), but not for the algorithm you provided.
- Collisions are [uniformly distributed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557231/are-sha1-hashes-distributed-uniformly).

Let's say our password is "password", which has eight characters. The number of alphanumeric passwords between one and eight characters is around 2.219e+14.

Let's also say the maximum password length is ten. Between nine and ten characters, there are 8.528e+17 passwords, or about 3800 times as many as between one and eight. Even if we assume five collisions, the likelihood that all five are longer than our "password" is around 99.9%.

The number I've used for max password length is (hopefully) much smaller than what is typically used, and the number of collisions is greatly overestimated. In practice, finding a collision that is shorter than the actual password just doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Any hashing algorithm that is used in practice should have a key space that is impossible to brute force. On the other hand, the set of actual passwords is much more limited, so attackers will not search all possible passwords, but only those that are used by real users.

Now if you have a good password, and an attacker does a brute force attack, it is not impossible that a different password would have the same hash. If the key space of the hash was only 64 bits, then among a few billion passwords you could expect that two have the same hash code. So it is not impossible that an attacker would find a different password with the same hash (after checking 2^64 passwords on average). Both would work for the attacker to get to the service. In reality, the hash algorithm should have a much larger key space and nobody will *ever* find a different password with the same hash.

Finding that alternative password lets you log into a service. But most attackers explicitely want the *password* because they are not interested in some unimportant service but hope that you will use the same password with other services. So the alternative password will be completely useless to them unless another service uses the exact same hashing algorithm and the exact same salt.

Answer (score -1):

> Does it matter if a brute force search for a password returns a collision and not the password?

If a password is the only mechanism for accessing a resource, it *often* does not matter if it is exact or a collision.  If you enter "dog" or "cat" and your hashing algorithm was *string.length*, then either will grant you access.

While this is often the case, it is also a matter of the program/service's implementation details.  For instance, a site/service may perform authenticity and runtime validity checks, which assess the password and where the password is coming from.  So even if "dog" and "cat" could grant access, if the middleman has a rule that passwords can't begin with "d" then that collision is out.

Additionally, some more secure services sometimes collect metadata (also hashed) on the supplied password (e.g., length, number of bytes, etc.) and inconsistencies in that metadata is sometimes used to flag, deny access, or reset password to accounts.

---

### OP Example

```
h(3) = 3 mod 17 = 3
```

> Is the problem that the password hashing space (0-16) is much smaller than the space of the allowed password, or is there something else I'm overlooking?

To address your question of the problem; there are many problems with the example; including, simplicity and too many potential collisions.  Without any rules of enforcement, the issue isn't about the entry window size.  The problem is the hashing algorithm leads to too many collisions; 3 plus multiples of 17 (`{3,20,37,54...}`) all result in 3.

The collisions are what’s important because it’s the hash that is used for authentication and verification; if the brute force can enter the 20 or 37 or 54... and still access the account or resource, the original password doesn’t matter.

To circle back to the original question, it is often the case that all that is required is the collision.  In fact, this is often how WiFi intrusion works.  The hash is found, which allows connection to the password-protected gateway.

Comment: First, the hashing algorithm was intentionally used to make it easy for to show a collision.  Second, I don't think salts are really relevant.  Salts are a unique per user nounce. They typically help to avoid precomputed attacks. So it's both out of the scope because this is only considering one user and because we're talking about brute force, not a precomputed attach.

Comment: @MikeSchem thank you. I consider salts relative. In fact, now that I view the other two answers for what’s been accepted by the community, one talks about a dictionary (a form of pre-computation) and the other mentions salts. By your standard, are we all in violation? The question also wasn’t clear what was being attacked, it was about brute forcing. You can brute force your way into an email account, which your input would go through a hashing algorithm, or you might brute force your way into the underlying database

Comment: I believe OP is asking if there's a practical difference between finding the real password and finding a collision, which the other answers do speak to. This answer is mostly about the probability of finding a collision in the first place, which, as I understand the question, is besides the point.

Comment: @JoshEller ah, thank you. I don't consider it beside the point.  I think the crux of what was mentioned was `if the brute force can enter the 20 or 37 or 54... and still access the account or resource, the original password doesn’t matter` the practical difference is none.  Perhaps I can make that clearer

Comment: @JoshEller I removed most of the commentary and delved more into what you mention as the heart of the question.  Does that seem more suitable?